# How to display alert when api(json) has no data in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, api, swift2, tableview

I am developing an app using Swift 2.2. In my app I am parsing (API) JSON data to table view when API has some data, I am able to parse it, but when API has no data, my app is terminating (crashing) so help me to display present view controller without terminating the app.

code in my view controller:

```
func jsonParsingFromURL () {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.something.com")
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    self.startParsing(data!)
}

func startParsing(data: NSData){
    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
    for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("driver_schedule") as! NSArray).count ; i++
    {
        arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("driver_schedule") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
        TableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: When it fails, what's the error exactly in console?

Comment: fatal error only because api has no data means it gives this error and crashing my app

Comment: if api has any data means no problem it parse into my table view without any problem

Comment: which error are come

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: could you please print response and data on console and paste it here

Comment: fatal error unexpectedly found nil value while unwrapping a value

Comment: @rajkumar check my updated answer

Comment: an internal error occurred source editor functionality is limited attempting to restore xcode...am getting this as warning how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```
if let elim = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
{
    // Write your code here
    // Check whether it has value or not
    self.nullToNil(dict["driver_schedule"] as? String)!

    print("Valid")
}
else {
      print("Print here")
}

do {      
   var Arr: NSArray!
   Arr = dict.objectForKey("driver_schedule")! as! NSArray
   if(Arr.count > 0)
   {
      for x in 0... Arr.count - 1
      {
        let str = Arr.objectAtIndex(i)
        if(str.length > 0)
        {
          arrDict.addObject(Arr.objectAtIndex(i))
          TableView.reloadData()
        }
       }
    }
} catch _{}
/*override func nullToNil(value : String?) -> String?
{
    if value == nil
    {
        let str:String = ""
        return str
    }
    else
    {
        return value
    }
}*/
```

Comment: i have to use for loop is there possible here

Comment: @rajkumar check my answer i used for loop

Comment: an internal error occurred source editor functionality is limited attempting to restore xcode...am getting this as warning how to solve this

Comment: @rajkumar check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805017/an-internal-error-occurred-source-editor-functionality-is-limited-attempting

Answer (score 0):

Create the following function which will allow you to display alert box:

```
func displayAlertMessage(msg: String){

    let alert=UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction=UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and in your function jsonParsingFromURL check if response is nil,if its nil then call displayAlertMessage function to show alert box like this:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock
    {
        self.displayAlertMessage("Your message");
    }
```

"**NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock**" will allow you to call your function in the main ui thread,Since you are calling it inside another thread that is running asynchronously.

Comment: an internal error occurred source editor functionality is limited attempting to restore xcode...am getting this as warning how to solve this